# On click next active element with specific class, trigger function

Tags: jquery, triggers, click, jquery-selectors

I've got a slider with some panels that slide in and out using arrows. The function for the next arrow is this:

```
var element = $('.projects .popup.active'),    
    next = $('.slider.projects #next'),
    prev = $('.slider.projects #prev'),
    oleft = element.offset().left,
    oright = ($(window).width() - (element.offset().left + element.outerWidth()));

next.unbind("click").on('click', function(e){   
        e.preventDefault();
        $(document).scrollTop(0);
        $('.projects .popup').not(element).removeClass('active');
        element.next('.popup').addClass('active');
        element.prevAll('.popup').css({zIndex: -1});
        element.prevAll('.popup').css({left:'-100%', margin: 0});
        element.nextAll('.popup').css({left:'100%', margin: 0});

        element.removeClass('active');
        element = $('.projects .popup.active');

        element.animate({
            left: '50%',
            marginLeft: -352.5
        },500);
        element.next('.popup').animate({
            left: $(window).width() - (oright / 2),
            marginLeft: 0
        },500);
        element.prev('.popup').animate({
            left: - elemWidth + (oleft / 2),
            marginLeft:0
        }, 500);
        checkarrow();
    });
```

I would like that also when clicking on the next or previous visible panel, the next and prev function is triggered. So, for the next panel, I have done this:

```
element.next('.popup').on('click', function(e){
    next.trigger('click');
});
```

This works fine the first time, but the second time, the click only works on the first

```
element.next('popup')
```

that has been clicked the first time. The class active updates fine, but the click doesn't work on the next panel. I can't figure out a solution.

Here is a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3sSz2/

Any help would be really appreciated.
Thanks in advance

**Update**

Thanks to f00bar I've managed to make the next boxes slide in fine. The previous ones although are not working as expected. The issue should be from line 100,  probably line 103 in this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3sSz2/11/.

When clicking on next box(the one on the right) or the next arrow, the next slide slides in, and again the next one after that does the same thing. When clicking on the central active slide nothing should happen. When clicking on the previous arrow or previous box (the one on the left) the box on the left should slide to the center and the central box should move to the right.

Please help, I know I'm almost there. Thanks

Comment: Fiddle please, then I will be able to help `;)`

Comment: Thanks f00bar, here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3sSz2/. As you will be able to see, when you click on the next box, it will slide in fine. Then clicking on the third box it won't work, but clicking again on the second box it works. But that isn't correct. Thanks again

Comment: Well, what would you like to happen when clicking the last box ?

Comment: That the last box slides in to the center and the second box slides left, and so on if there are more boxes after the third one. I hope that my code makes sense. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: I'm not sure what you actually want the slider to render ... check this [Fiddle revision](http://jsfiddle.net/f00bar/3sSz2/6/)

Comment: That is amazing, you are amazing, but not quite right. The active slider shouldn't have the click and slide effect, only the next one. Also, my bad, I didn't mention that there is a prev arrow as well and therefore when clicking on the previous box it slides in the opposite way. Please take a look at the new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/3sSz2/7/. Thank you

Comment: The functionality you have created is almost there. When clicking on next box(the one on the right) or the next arrow, the next slide slides in, and again the next one after that does the same thing. When clicking on the central active slide nothing should happen. When clicking on the previous arrow or previous box (the one on the left) the box on the left should slide to the center and the central box should move to the right. Thank you so much again

Comment: Does it has to loop ? ... What happen when the last box is in the middle and then one clicks the 'next' button ?

Comment: Well, if it has the loop function it would be ideal, but currently it doesn't have the loop. When the last box is in the middle the 'next' button disappears. Did you see my latest update? There is a new [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3sSz2/11/) Thanks again @f00bar

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39729/discussion-between-f00bar-and-jeff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, this is what I ended up with and I hope it will help considering the time I spent writing [THIS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/stphane/7s2XV/) `Oo`

I attached the click handler on the .slider element to avoid multiple listener..
Here it the handler.

```
$('.slider').click(function (e) {
    var $slider = $(this),
        data = $slider.data('slider'),
        $slides = $slider.find('.popup'),
        $first = $slides.eq(0),
        $last = $slides.last(),
        $activeItem = $slides.filter('.active'),
        $next = $('.popup-nav.next', this),
        $prev = $('.popup-nav.prev', this),
        $t = $(e.target).closest('.popup, .popup-nav'),
        $nextItem = $activeItem.next('.popup'),
        $prevItem = $activeItem.prev('.popup'),
        way = (
            // Is the target be the next item in the DOM or the 'next arrow'
            ($t.is('.popup-nav.next') || $t.is($nextItem)) ? -1 :
            // Is the target be the next item in the DOM or the 'prev arrow'
            ($t.is('.popup-nav.prev') || $t.is($nextItem)) ? 1 : 0
        );

    switch (way) {
    // previous
    case 1:
        // if the active slide is the last project
        if ($activeItem.is($first)) {
            $first.before($last.css({
                left: +($first.css('left').replace('px', '')) - data.width
            }));
        }
        $activeItem.removeClass('active').prev().addClass('active');
        play.call($slides, {
            way: way,
            width: data.width
        });
        break;
    // next
    case -1:
        // if the active slide is the last project
        if ($activeItem.is($last)) {
            $last.after($first.css({
                left: +($last.css('left').replace('px', '')) + data.width
            }));
        }
        $activeItem.removeClass('active').next().addClass('active');
        play.call($slides, {
            way: way,
            width: data.width
        });
        break;
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi @Jeff, I forgot to set my last fiddle edit to be the base script .. clicking the previous element actually works [can you confirm this ?] and I might set some flags somewhere to prevent animation collisions ..! By the way I can still give you a hand with your project ... but from now on we should discuss in private message I think  `;)` A Pint !? What a kind attention `:D`

Comment: Thank you, it works amazingly! How could I contact you privately?